# How to get duplicate files numbered as file1.txt_1, file1.txt_2, file.txt_3 when copying in BASH?

Tags: bash, cp

In a script, I need to copy files from several directories, into one directory, e.g.:

```
$ dir
dir1    dir2    dir3    output
$ cp */* output/
```

Sometimes, there are files with the same name though:

```
$ ls dir1/*
file1.txt
$ ls dir2/*
file1.txt
$ ls dir3/*
file1.txt
```

How can I copy all of the files from the different directories, into a single directory, without with the filenames changed whenever two files with identical names are placed in the same directory? Sample result:

```
$ cp */* output/
$ ls output/
file1.txt_1
file1.txt_2
file1.txt_3
```

Comment: Do you care which order the suffixes are created in? Does the first file copied need to be the first numbered copy? Do you need `_1`, `_2`, `_3`? Or will `file1.txt`, `file1.txt_1`, `file1.txt_2` work?

Comment: `file1.txt`, `file1.txt_1`, `file1.txt_2`, is also fine, if the other way is too complicated or difficult. It is best if the order is the same order the files are copied in, so the `dir1/` has the lowest number, `dir2` is second, etc.

Answer (score 5):

A pretty simple way to do this is use the `--backup` flag to `cp`. It will back up files which are replaced rather than leaving them, but that might be sufficient. This approach is simple enough it would be easy to wrap an alias around.

```
source
├── dir1
│   └── file1.txt
├── dir2
│   └── file2.txt
├── dir3
│   └── file1.txt
└── dir4
    └── file10.txt
```

```
cp --backup=numbered source/dir*/* dest
```

```
$ tree dest
dest
├── file1.txt
├── file1.txt.~1~
├── file10.txt
└── file2.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but [not all `cp` versions support that](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html).

Comment: Oh - fair point. This option is present on GNU cp 8.22 but not on the latest BSD cp shipping on OSX. I always put the GNU tools in the front of my interactive shell toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little trouble with the `_number`, but if you're ok with the syntax as `file.txt` `file.txt.1` `file.txt.2` `file.txt.3` then this should work

```
#!/bin/bash

treedir="/path/to/tree"

cd $treedir

for folder in * ; do
    if [ -d "$folder" ] && [ "$folder" != "output" ] ; then
            cd "$folder"
            for file in * ; do

                    if [ -e "$treedir/output/$file" ] ; then

                            fcount=$(grep -s "" "$treedir/$file.count")

                            if [ -n "$fcount" ] ; then
                                    fcount=$(( fcount + 1 ))
                                    echo $fcount > "$treedir/$file.count"
                            else
                                     fcount=1
                                     echo $fcount > "$treedir/$file.count"
                            fi

                            cp "$file" "$treedir/output/$file.$fcount"
                    else    

                            cp "$file" "$treedir/output/$file"
                    fi

            done
            cd ..
    fi
done

rm *.count

exit 0
```

This creates temporary *.count files to keep track of how many files of the same name there are and then it deletes them in the end.

Just replace `"/path/to/tree/"` with the path to the directory containing your `dir1 dir2 dir3 output` etc. and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

There is another, perhaps shorter way to insure a unique copy name when consolidating files from multiple directories. The following will copy all files (one level deep) from multiple directories into a single output_dir and add the minimum `file_#` index to insure unique filenames (if more depth is needed -- use `find`):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( path/to/*/* )                     # fill array with files to be copied

for file in ${arr[@]}; do               # for each file
    idx=0                               # set the copy index to 0
    dfn=${file##*/}                     # destination file name (dfn) w/path stripped
    while [ -f output_dir/"$dfn" ] ; do # test if $dfn exist in output_dir
        dfn=${file##*/}_$((idx++))      # if so, add copy index "_#" (increment until unique)
    done
    cp "$file" ../c/"$dfn"              # copy file with unique file name
done
```

**input dir: `tmp/*/*`**

```
tmp/a/a.j
tmp/a/a.k
tmp/a/a.l
tmp/a/a.txt
tmp/b/a.j
tmp/b/a.k
tmp/b/a.l
tmp/c/a.j
tmp/c/a.k
tmp/c/a.l
tmp/c/a.txt
tmp/d/a.j
tmp/d/a.k
tmp/d/a.l
tmp/d/a.txt
```

**output_dir: `output`**

```
a.j
a.j_0
a.j_1
a.j_2
a.k
a.k_0
a.k_1
a.k_2
a.l
a.l_0
a.l_1
a.l_2
a.txt
a.txt_0
a.txt_1
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
declare -A indexes
for file in */*
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    index=${indexes[$name]}
    if [ -z "$index" ]
    then
        cp "$file" output/
        indexes[$name]=1
    else
        cp "$file" output/"$name"_$index
        indexes[$name]=$((index+1))
    fi
done
unset indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach if you don't have a modern GNU cp available would be to use the source directory as the suffix. This is simpler than some approaches as you don't have to do any counting and you don't have to use an array.

```
SOURCE=$1
DEST=$2
for i in $(find $SOURCE -type f) ; do
  if [[ -r $DEST/$(basename $i) ]] ; then
NEW_NAME=$(basename $i)_$(basename $(dirname $i))
cp $i $DEST/$NEW_NAME
  else
cp $i $DEST/
  fi
done


$ tree source
source
├── dest
├── dir1
│   └── file1.txt
├── dir2
│   └── file2.txt
├── dir3
│   └── file1.txt
└── dir4
└── file10.txt

$ bash ./copy.sh source dest
$ tree dest
dest
├── file1.txt
├── file1.txt_dir3
├── file10.txt
└── file2.txt
```